# Online Quiz Application check selected Radio Button

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing online quiz..in this i use use four radio buttons. And i bind answers in it..at a time only one ques with ans will displayed in page..By clicking Next button Next question with ans will bind in same fields...My problem is User ans for for every question..when user click Previous button previous Question with answer will bind.But the radio button is not in check..i want to check the Radio Buttons which was selected by users....

my code for Next Button to bind is

```
QuesinsertBOL bol = new QuesinsertBOL();
    QuesinsertBAL bal = new QuesinsertBAL();
    dt = bal.selectques(bol);
    ViewState["i"] = (int)ViewState["i"] - 1;
    int i = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["i"]);
    int a = 0;
    if (i >a)
    {
        if (dt != null || i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            lblQuest.Text = dt.Rows[i]["question"].ToString();
            rdbch1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["opt1"].ToString();
            rdbch2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["opt2"].ToString();
            rdbch3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["opt3"].ToString();
            rdbch4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["opt4"].ToString();
            txtans.Text = dt.Rows[i]["correctans"].ToString();
            btnnxt.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    else
    {
        btnprevious.Enabled = false;

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using basic radio buttons you'll need to determine which button matches the **value** and then issue a line like this:

```
rdbch1.Checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Clicking Next Button,
You can save your selected radio button value and question number in the session and when Previous Button will click, you can retrieve that values from session and will be select your Radio Button.

Comment: But i use same page for bind all the questions

Comment: on next and previous button , postback event (page reload) is called ??

Comment: no it will not be called